# android how to set buttons in layout for all resolution

Tags: android, layout, android-button

i have set button inside Linear layout for 10.1" resolution is 1280x800 ,its set properly       but its not set for 7" resolution 1024x600 .Can someone please suggest how to set this button for all resolution?

This is my xml file set background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/kids">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/kids_first"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kids_second"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kids_third"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your UI? give any screenshot that you want.

Comment: give android:layout_weight=1 to every button. It will automatically on each screen size. or change  android:layout_width="match parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap content"

Comment: post the screenshot that you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kids_first"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kids_second"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kids_third"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="3"   
 android:background="@drawable/kids">

<Button
android:id="@+id/kids_first"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_gravity="right" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/kids_second"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Button" 
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_marginTop="240dp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/kids_third"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Button" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```